# Problem with posting json to my web-api. How can i solve it

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, http-post, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new in web api and now make a simple program using .net 3
In my controller i am create simple post method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Post(CountryPostRequest countryPostRequest)
{
    var savedCity = new City {Name=countryPostRequest.Capital};
    var savedRegion = countryDb.Regions.Add(new Region { Name = countryPostRequest.Region });
    var savedCountry = countryDb.Countries.Add(new Countrie { Name = countryPostRequest.Name, Region = new Region { Name = countryPostRequest.Region }, Capital = savedCity, AreaSize = countryPostRequest.AreaSize, CountryCode = countryPostRequest.CountryCode, Population = countryPostRequest.Population });
    countryDb.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Get));
}
```

This method get a CountryPostRequest. It's looks like that

```
public class CountryPostRequest
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string CountryCode { set; get; }
    public int Population { set; get; }
    public double AreaSize { set; get; }
    public string Capital { set; get; }
    public string Region { set; get; }
}
```

Overall i try to post this raw using postman

```
{
   "Name" : "Roman Empire",
   "CountryCode" : "RE",
   "Population" : 22,
   "AreaSize": 22.0,
   "Capital" : "Rome",
   "Region" : "EU"
}
```

And postman give me a result:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13",
    "title": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "status": 415,
    "traceId": "|db653ff6-46b8be8826b56364."
}
```

Get methods works fine. What's incorrect? Help please

Comment: You need to set the content-type in postman as `JSON (application/json)`. Go to the body inside your POST request, there you will find the raw option. Right next to it, there will be a drop down, select JSON

Comment: Fine thank you @RahulSharma

Comment: Ye-------------------------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically for your case, since you are using `postman` to call your API:

You need to set the content-type in postman as JSON (application/json). Go to the body inside your POST request, there you will find the raw option. Right next to it, there will be a drop down, select JSON.